# Variables not being replaced by values in string fetched by file_get_contents()

Tags: php, templates, file-get-contents

I have a file where I store multiple templates with a delimiter. I fetch the contents using file_get_contents(), then parse them using preg_match_all().
In these templates I include variables, which I expected to be replaced by their values, as I use the curly braces method as can be done in strings (see example below). Does anyone have any tips on why this isn't working?

code.tpl:

```
### CHAPTER_FILE_LIST START ###
<item id="{$CHAPTER['id']}" href="{$CHAPTER['file']}.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
### CHAPTER_FILE_LIST END ###

### CHAPTER_LIST START ###
<itemref idref="{$CHAPTER['id']}"/>
### CHAPTER_LIST END ###
```

PHP file

```
function grab_templates() {
    global $tpl;
    if($raw_tpl = file_get_contents('templates/code.tpl')) {
        preg_match_all('/### ([A-Za-z._]+) START ###\s*([^#]+)### \1 END ###\s*/', $raw_tpl, $tpl_array);

        $count = count($tpl_array[1]);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $tpl[$tpl_array[1][$i]] = $tpl_array[2][$i];
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Error getting code.tpl';
        exit;
    }
}

grab_templates();
$CHAPTER['id'] = 'name_of_chapter';
$CHAPTER['file'] = 'chapter_file';

echo $tpl['CHAPTER_FILE_LIST'].'<br />';
echo $tpl['CHAPTER_LIST'];
```

This should define template variables: `$tpl['CHAPTER_FILE_LIST']` and `$tpl['CHAPTER_LIST']`and output:

```
<item id="name_of_chapter" href="chapter_file.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<itemref idref="name_of_chapter"/>
```

but instead it's outputting:

```
<item id="{$CHAPTER['id']}" href="{$CHAPTER['file']}.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<itemref idref="{$CHAPTER['id']}"/>
```

Comment: you never replace `{$CHAPTER['id']}` with another value, and the string is never "parsed", so php won't replace them either. There might be a workaround via eval, but I'd recommend a preg_replace with a different placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You can try modify your code.

In code.tpl :

```
### CHAPTER_FILE_LIST START ###
<item id="[CHAPTER_ID]" href="[CHAPTER_FILE].xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
### CHAPTER_FILE_LIST END ###

### CHAPTER_LIST START ###
<itemref idref="[CHAPTER_ID]"/>
### CHAPTER_LIST END ###
```

In your PHP file :

```
$vars = array("[CHAPTER_ID]" => "name_of_chapter", "[CHAPTER_FILE]" => "chapter_file"); 

function grab_templates() {
    global $tpl;
    global $vars;
    if($raw_tpl = file_get_contents('templates/code.tpl')) {
        preg_match_all('/### ([A-Za-z._]+) START ###\s*([^#]+)### \1 END ###\s*/', $raw_tpl, $tpl_array);
        $count = count($tpl_array[1]);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $tpl[$tpl_array[1][$i]] = str_replace(array_keys($vars), array_values($vars), $tpl_array[2][$i]);
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Error getting code.tpl';
        exit;
    }
}

grab_templates();
echo $tpl['CHAPTER_FILE_LIST'].'<br />';
echo $tpl['CHAPTER_LIST'];
```

Comment: I know I can implement a str_replace method, and I'll probably end up doing that, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm still curious as to why the curly braces method is not working though (for future reference). According to the documentation, this should work when done within a string, and file_get_contents() imports the file's contents into a string. So why isn't it? I'm guessing it's because the function retrieves the data as a "single quoted" string, so variables aren"t evaluated, so I'm wondering if there is a way to change that.